# Javascript mouseleave/mouseenter won't fire while left button held down?

Tags: javascript, button, mouse, mouseenter

As the title says; I have a javascript mouseleave and mouseenter events, but they don't fire when left mouse button is held down(they run fine if middle or right button is held). Why? and is there a way?

```
document.onmouseleave = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log(e.which);
}
document.onmouseenter = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log(e.which);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are selecting text when the left mouse button is held down.

Comment: I thought about that, but I tried adding this to css on body

    body{
  background-color:#999;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
 }

that doesn't help..

Comment: @user3591153 that CSS will not affect JavaScript in this case.

Comment: any suggestions on what will?

Comment: Nope to my knowledge you can't

Answer (score 0):

!! so I had an idea of using a div and with some experimenting I managed to figure out a workaround !!

I add a div inside the body

```
<div id="bodyBlock"></div>
```

then I add some css

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

#bodyBlock{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    border:0px none #000;
    background-color:#111;
    z-index:-10;
}
```

Now it works!
It seems like the div blocks the clicks on the body, and when mouse leaves/enters, it will log the left button when held down(as well as the other buttons)!